# Why does building the same gemspec multiple times create different gem binaries?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When building a gem via `gem build GEMSPEC`, the created .gem file is different each time despite nothing in the code or gemspec changing. To demonstrate, I'll use the hola repository that is linked in the [Make your own gem](https://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) page on RubyGems.org:

```sh
$ git clone https://github.com/qrush/hola
$ cd hola
$ gem build hola.gemspec -o 1.gem
$ gem build hola.gemspec -o 2.gem
```

Using `diff` and `sha512sum` you can clearly see that the binaries generated are not the same:

```sh
$ diff 1.gem 2.gem
Binary files 1.gem and 2.gem differ
```

```sh
$ sha512sum ./*.gem
288a329f69febb51288bea381275688172e2d13fb13ee0868e910e7e0efdaf1e330b158502ce01378eff637f8d18aa8d8c4f6d9c2922deb92a4018ddacdc0624  ./1.gem
cb35b0e1eabfd3d6b0bff698a7d79caf2bcb6e71781134702857fde8619bc09a451284984ac0394a27c7266e5313374d98c2a1502d2ad89a97de1ac10844978c  ./2.gem
```

Why is this happening? Is there any way to get `gem build` to output the same binary? If not, is there a way to validate the contents of a built gem is the same as another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A gemfile is basically a tar archive, and tar preserves things like file modification timestamps which will change.  See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/346789/compressing-two-identical-folders-give-different-result) for a more thorough investigation of this phenomenon.

Comment: Thank you! That answers the why and helped me find the best way to get a proper checksum for the contents: `tar -xzOf 1.gem data.tar.gz | tar -xO | sha512sum`